# Google sheets through Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

As on my corporate network google sheets are not allowed I am trying to access it via reverse proxy from my server. All other proxy services I have in my Apache configuration work without problems.

```
ProxyPass /sheets/ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0
ProxyPassReverse /sheets/ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0
```

xxxxxxxxxxx in the code above represents my spreadsheet ID. I consistently get 500 internal server error, also when changing the destination url to exclude the spreadsheet id. Chrome network analysis throws this:

```
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Has anyone solved this or is it blocked by google by default?

Comment: Is your server not on your corporate network?

Comment: No, server is elsewhere. I can access it from the corporate network.

Comment: I suspect that the call is trying to make other direct calls to google.com which is what leads to the "cross origin" problem.  If you could figure out how to subvert those security protocols, I am sure your IT department would not be pleased.